# PHP > Dealing with numbers

Tags: php

I have a question and I don't know what is the correct term to use in search!

what PHP function should I use to print the number like this

Original number > Expected result

15001 > 15000

16300 > 16000

22700 > 22000

I mean to remove all numbers after the thousands

any help ?

Comment: what expected results are you looking to get?

Comment: You need to show the input and output you are trying to get

Comment: I update my question

Comment: And what if the number is `47` or `567` or `1234`? Will it be zero in all cases?

Comment: Your first 2 I can understand to round off, but the 3rd doesn't, since 22700 is closer to 23000 then 22000. This is what "I" was taught in basic math.

Comment: I have a rule to set any umber under 1000 to 1000 and for 1234 would be 1000

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can accept a solution that any number above 500 to be 1000

like 22500 or 22700 would be 23000

Comment: you've been given an answer below, check that out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, this work with me , but can I also have your solution ? 

 like 22500 or 22700 would be 23000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some math:

Divide the `$number` by 1000, round fractions down with `floor` or `ceil`, then multiply it by 1000.

```
$number = 22700;
// if ($number < 1000) { /* don't apply this */ }

echo floor($number / 1000) * 1000; // 22000
// or
echo ceil($number / 1000) * 1000; // 23000
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to rome:

```
foreach([1,12,123,1234,12345,123456,1234567] as $num){
    print $num. " > ". (substr($num,-1*strlen($num),-3)."000") . '<br>';
}
//result: 
//1 > 000
//12 > 000
//123 > 000
//1234 > 1000
//12345 > 12000
//123456 > 123000
//1234567 > 1234000
```

No rounding here. Just replacing.